# Why this integral does not work to calculate Cut Cone Volume?

Tags: geometry

I have already solved the problem through another way, but I'm puzzled why this approach I tried does not work.

I need to say the height of water a glass should have in order to have an amount `L/N` `ml` of water. The glass is a frustum of a cone. Being the smallest base the one that touches the table (If you want, check the image [here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1549))

What is given: Radius of bases (`b` and `B`), (smallest one is `b`), the height of the glass (H), all of them in `cm`, `L` and `N` (`L` in `ml` and `N` is a number).
What I want: The water height inside the glass, `h`, in order to have an amount `L/N` `ml` of water inside the glass.

What I thought:
Integrate from `b` to (`b+(B-b)*h/H`)  (`[PI * x^2] dx`)
The result will be the volume of water I have if the water reach `h` `cm` height.
So I make this result `= L/N` and get the `h`.

Example it does not work:

```
N=1, L=200
b=5, B=6, H=8
```

`h` should be aprox. `2.40`, but my formula gives me aprox. `14.50`.

The final formula I got is:

```
h = [ (3L/(PI*N) + b^3)^(1.0/3) -b ]*H/(B-b)
```

Comment: You can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1) at any rep level, @TheJoker.

Comment: It is like using LaTex, except with mathjax, you surround equations, fractions, variables, formulas, etc. with a $\$$ sign on each side (or two: $\$\$$ on each side of a longer expression.)

Comment: But when I try to send the formula the field says I don't have rep... I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the radius of a slice, then its height is not $dx$ but $H/(B-b)dx$. Hence you must compute
$$
\int_b^{b+(B-b)h/H}\pi x^2{H\over B-b}dx.
$$

[image]

Comment: Oh my god. I'm so dumb. Sorry.